# Open file from Firebase Storage in new table and not download

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I have various buckets in Firebase Storage that all contain an html file. What I want to do is through Javascript, get the URL of a particular HTML file in a bucket, and then open it in a new tab. When I use the 'getDownloadURL' method, and pass the url to window.open what I'm finding is that a new tab opens temporarily, the file gets downloaded, and then the tab closes. Ideally, I would like to completely avoid downloading the file, and just view it. I believe this is happening because of the format of the URL itself:
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/[project].appspot.com/o/[bucket]%2Fcreate.html?alt=media&token=[token]

Can anybody please help me use window.load to only open the html file in a new tab? I would prefer to not download the file at all, and I need the tab to remain open. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
var storage = firebase.storage();
var storageRef = storage.ref();
var reportFileRef = storageRef.child(currentUid + '/create.html');
reportFileRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
    window.open(url, '_blank')
});
```

Comment: An additional note... I believe this has to do with HTTP Content-Disposition headers. I might need to override the header, but I am currently unsure how:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#contentdisposition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the metadata correctly solved the Content-Disposition issue. Here is the function I've defined, where contenttype is either "text/html" or "image/png"

```
def uploadToFirebaseStorage(filename, filepath, user, report, contenttype):
    my_file = open(os.path.join(filepath, filename), "rb")
    my_bytes = my_file.read()
    my_url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/[project].appspot.com/o/" + filename
    my_headers = { "Content-Type": contenttype }
    my_request = urllib.request.Request(my_url, data=my_bytes, headers=my_headers)
    try:
        loader = urllib.request.urlopen(my_request)
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        message = json.loads(e.read())
        return message["error"]["message"]
    else:
        return loader.read()
```